# Question on finding the first term and common ratio of the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

The question states that "The sum, $S_n$, of the first $n$ terms of a geometric sequence, whose $nth$ term is $U_n$, is given by $S_n = \frac{7^n - a^n}{7^n}$ , where $a > 0$.

I have to find the first term and common ratio. I have figured out the first term which should be $\frac{7-a}{7}$ . I have thought of multiple equations to try and find the common ratio but I am having trouble figuring out. If anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Answer (score 3):

$S_1$ gives first term and $S_2$ gives sum of first two terms. Then $S_2-S_1$ is the second term, divide it by $S_1$ to get common ratio.

Answer (score 1):

If the ratio is $r$,
then
$S_n
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}U_0r^k
=U_0\dfrac{1-r^n}{1-r}
$.

So you want
$U_0\dfrac{1-r^n}{1-r}
= \dfrac{7^n - a^n}{7^n}
$.

Note that
$\dfrac{7^n - a^n}{7^n}
=1-\left(\frac a7\right)^n
$.

This should be enough.