# given that the sum of the first n terms of a geometric sequence is $4-(2^{(n+2)})/3^{(2n)}$. find the second term and its common ratio.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I tried to find the first term by substituting 1 into n, and I got $28/9$. After that, I subtitute $2$ into $n$ for $S_n$ and dis the $Term_2 = S_2 -S_1$. I wasn't sure whether I am correct or not. Can someone please guide me on how to solve this question?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please elaborate why you think "Term 2 = $S_2 - S_1$"

Comment: @Dstarred oh no, it is the wrong formula for geometric sequence. thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question on finding the first term and common ratio of the sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3378234/question-on-finding-the-first-term-and-common-ratio-of-the-sequence) especially [that answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3378259)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you already know how to solve the problem.

Let's denote the actual terms of the sequence by $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots$. Let $S_n = a_1 + a_2 + \dotsb + a_n$ be the sum of the first $n$ terms.

As you said, you can find the first term by plugging $n = 1$ into the formula for $S_n$:
$$a_1 = S_1 = 4 - 2^{1 + 2}/3^{2 \times 1} = \frac{28}{9}.$$

Since $S_1 = a_1$, $S_2 = a_1 + a_2$, you can recover the second term by
\begin{align*}
a_2 & = S_2 - S_1\\
& = \Big( 4 - \frac{2^{2 + 2}}{3^{2 \times 2}} \Big) - \frac{28}{9}\\
& = \frac{56}{81}.
\end{align*}

Since you are told that the sequence is geometric, the common ratio is just
$$q = \frac{a_2}{a_1} = \frac{\frac{56}{81}}{\frac{28}{9}} = \frac{2}{9}.$$

Comment: It was a (probably multiple) duplicate.